# Python selenium stale element error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Using python with selenium and the following code produces a stale element error, can anyone see why?

```
def test_set_language(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://somewebpage.com")
    elemL = driver.find_element_by_name("selectLang")
    elemL.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.assertIn("Mot", driver.page_source)
```

Comment: stale element exception throws when you interact with an element and it's changed in DOM. By taking a look at your script, it may be "elemL.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)". I couldnot tell more since I dont have much info

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown if between and interaction with that element page was reloaded or `DOM` model has changed.

Element lookup is first time when selenium assigned internal id to that element - see selenium execution logs for details.

If you can't provide better solution, you may want to use generic solution for `StaleElementReferenceException` - surround with `try/catch` block, in `catch` block wait a few seconds and retry operation. This is not an elegant solution, but this is what people have to do at times and what works just fine.